# prevent mobile safari scroll on x direction

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, html, mobile-safari

I implemented a div in mobile safari that has the same width as the device width and larger height than the device height:
I have used this meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
```

However, I can still scroll the screen. That means if you scroll to the left, some blank space will appear at the right hand side. I have tried the following:

```
$(document).on(isMobile ? 'touchmove' : 'mousemove', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

This does prevent the scrolling. However, I only want to prevent scrolling on the X direction. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: quick note: `body { overflow-x: hidden; }` should prevent horizontal scrolling

Answer (score 0):

Bit long for a comment. If your viewport settings are correct, it should really be as wide as the screen and scrolling should not be permitted. One possibility is that you have some element that went beyond the size of the viewport. But it's also possible that the device-width on the viewport is wrong. Forexample, for iphone/ipods, the width of the screen on portrait orientation is only 320px as opposed to it's 640px actual-pixel-count. If the device-width somehow gets 640px instead of 320px, your viewport is twice as large.
Try experiment with different viewport widths.